# JSON click event empty parameter

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3

Parameter `string Temat` is empty when I click button where is problem? It's look OK?

file.cshtml

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
    <table class="edt" style="float: left; width: 600px; margin-top: 5px; background-color: white;">
    <tr>
                <td class="labelm">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Temat)<span id="Temat_2" class="a">*</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Temat,  new { id = "Temat" })
                </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" value="save" onclick="Save();" />
    }

<script type="text/javascript">

    function Save() {
    var Temat = $('#Temat').val();

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("DodajTematSave", "StronaGlowna")',
                dataType: "json",
                data: { Temat: Temat },
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                error: function() {
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.Success) {
                        alert('success');
                    }

                }
            });
        }

</script>
```

JSON Method in Controller:

```
public JsonResult DodajTematSave(string Temat)
{
    var model = new StronaGlowna();
    if (!TryUpdateModel(model) || !ModelState.IsValid) // podładowanie yield 
    {
    }
    string chceSprobowac = Temat;
    return Json(new { Success = true});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you want to retrieve the value of the textbox. If so, assign the id 'Temat' to the text box rather than then span and your code should work fine.

But if you are interested to retrieve the text of the span then use

```
var Temat = $('#Temat').text();
```

If you want to assign id to the textbox,

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password, new { id = "Temat" })
```

Comment: I gave got problem with test it because @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Temat) and @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Temat, new { size = 47 }) have got similar id how shuld I change it for one of them?

Comment: Value is empty in textbox but I don`t know why before I get "*" this was text from span but I need text from textbox.

Comment: Just assign the id 'Temat' to the text box and remove it from the span. your code should work fine.

Comment: I check and it`s not work. I don`t know why. I can`t get data from textBox

Comment: code looks okay now. Can you check the generated html from the browser and see if the id has been set correctly?

Comment: Now this working var Temat2 = $('#Temat').val(); before was problem with span where two controls have similar ID (this not work $('#Temat').text();)Thanks for help

Comment: I hope this example will be useful for other users Thanks again!