# JSON TinyMCE return value "\t"

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, tinymce

Should I use another variable for "streszczenie"? or what should I do?

In my opinion in TinyMCE body have html but I get only **"\t"** Pobably I have got problem with JS

[this is new problem - this question is related with this link. I added this for other users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597252/json-click-event-empty-parameter)

**this I write in TinyMCE**

[image]

**this I get from TinyMCE textarea "streszczenie"**

[image]

As you can see there is text **ghhfgh** but I can`t get this text

[image]

Now I have got problem with execute JSON

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function Save() {
        tinyMCE.triggerSave();
        var Temat_controll = $('#Temat').val();
        var Streszczenie_controll = tinyMCE.get('Streszczenie').getContent();
        var PelnyOpis_controll = $('#PelnyOpis').text();

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("DodajTematSave", "StronaGlowna")',
                dataType: "json",
                data: { 
                    Temat: Temat_controll,
                    Streszczenie: Streszczenie_controll,
                    PelnyOpis: PelnyOpis_controll
                },
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                error: function() {
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.Success) {
                        alert('success');
                    }

                }
            });
        }

</script>
```

I get this but all the time JSON is not execute

[image]

When I click button tinyMCE.get('Streszczenie').getContent() is empty I check this and I don`t know why because I have got text into textarea

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function Save() {
        var Temat_controll = $('#Temat').val();
        var $d = tinyMCE.get('Streszczenie').getContent();
        if ($d.length != 0) {
            if ($d.val().length != 0) {
                var Streszczenie_controll = tinyMCE.get('Streszczenie').getContent();
            }
            else {
                var Streszczenie_controll = 'ewewe';
            }
        }
        var PelnyOpis_controll = $('#PelnyOpis').text();

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("DodajTematSave", "StronaGlowna")',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                Temat: Temat_controll,
                Streszczenie: Streszczenie_controll,
                PelnyOpis: PelnyOpis_controll
            },
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            error: function () {
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.Success) {
                    alert('success');
                }

            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: This link can be also useful to understand JSON problem [click here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15600396/json-data-html-parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the content in wrong way, not by jQuery's `val()`.

To get the tinymce content, just use `tinyMCE` object reference:

```
// Get the HTML contents of the currently active editor
console.debug(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent());

// Get the raw contents of the currently active editor
tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({format : 'raw'});

// Get content of a specific editor:
tinyMCE.get('content id').getContent()
```

As mentioned:
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.getContent

Hope it heled. Polish man : )

Comment: Can you look on my JSON script I write this var Streszczenie_controll = tinyMCE.get('#Streszczenie').getContent(); but now I have got problem with execute JSON

Comment: Man, you are selecting wrong the element by `get()` method. It works such as `getElementById()` syntax, so you cannot use `#` at the beggining (read the docs carfully http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.get). Or just use `tinyMCE.activeEditor` instead of `tinyMCE.get()`.

Comment: Try debug it by `console.log(Streszczenie_controll)` or `alert(Streszczenie_controll)`. What `id` have the textarea that you appiled the TinyMCE to? The `id` attribute should be passed to `get()` function as a parameter. Try to use `tinyMCE.activeEditor`.

Comment: as you can see in edited my post this working tinyMCE.get('Streszczenie').getContent() but I can`t send this information to JSON probably I should write something like this tinyMCE.get('Streszczenie').getContent().toString() but I don`t know how.

Comment: No. The function `getContent()` returns the string. Did you read the docs? That are the debug reults?

Comment: Can you look into my edited post. Maybe you know why tinyMCE.get('Streszczenie').getContent() is empty

Comment: Of course I will not debug your code. I just solved your problem by receiving contents from the editor. BTW: why are you assign the string HTML contents ino `$()` object? You should check if: `tinyMCE.get('Streszczenie').getContent().length != 0`

Comment: I don`t want to debug my code by you but maybe you have another idea where can be problem

Comment: Solution in comment above.

Comment: I found problem JSON have got problem with text like this var Streszczenie_controll = '<p></p><t></t>'; for him right part is not a string

Comment: Have you finally sloved problem with using `getContent()`?

Comment: Yes getContent() working correct all the time but there is a problem with JSON. I will accept your answer and I will try fix this problem by myself. Thanks for your time. I will not forget also give you points.